# Symfony 4 : validator is refreshing instead of displaying message

Tags: php, symfony, constraints, symfony-forms, symfony-4.3

I have a [symfony add form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMqFI.png) , and on "client" section are 2 possibilities (either a client already exists, and it s selected from db, either it doesn t exist and you have to complete [additional fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR38b.png) that are imported as CollectionFormType). When you create a new client, his phone number must be unique, so I tried adding a custom constraint "checkUnique" that check for duplicates and for format.

The problem is that, when a constraint condition from newClient field (phone) is met, the page is refreshing getting a [violation "phone already exists"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO95k.png)   instead of displaying a message like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIUW5.png). How can I stop the page from submitting and display a message to change the phone number, without refresh?

---

CollectionFormType "NewClientType" that I used:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    etc just important
    $builder
        ->add('phone', TextType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => $this->translator->trans('Telefon'),
            'constraints'=>[
                new NotBlank(['message' => $this->translator->trans('Câmpul este obligatoriu')]),
                new Callback(array($this, 'checkUnique'))
            ],
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => $this->translator->trans('Telefon')
            )
        ));

}

public function checkUnique($value, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    $form = $context->getRoot();
    $data = $form->getData();
    $phone = str_replace("+","00",$context->getValue());
    if (!ctype_digit($phone)) {
        $context->buildViolation($this->translator->trans("Format invalid"))
            ->addViolation();
    } else if ($this->entityManager->getRepository(Clients::class)->findOneBy(["phone" => $phone])) {
        $context->buildViolation($this->translator->trans("Telefonul exista deja"))
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

---

FormType which contains CollectionFormType "NewClientType":

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    etc just important
    $form->add('newClient', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => ClientsNewType::class,
        'allow_add'    => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ]);
}
```

(I'm using Prototype to render this form).

Comment: That's a client side validation, so you'll have to do this with some javascript.

Comment: @msg But it s not ok for me with js  due  to terms  of vulnerability. Do you have an advice   for me?

Comment: You can use the [`pattern attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression) for format validation, that's built-in in the browser, but for checking if the phone already exists you need a roundtrip to the server, either by form submission or ajax.

Comment: @msg so there is no way to stop submittin the form in "pre_submit" ?

Comment: Well, yes, using javascript or html5 validation (`pattern`), but that's only going to get you so far... If you want to customize the error message or do something more advanced, you'll have to use javascript.

Comment: The "pre_submit" event is triggered before the submitted data is passed to the form. It still happens after sending the data to your web server, so it will not help you. PHP is a server side language. For Symfony to be able to process your form data you will always have to submit it. The only way around this would be to send a list of registered phone numbers to the client so that you can validate them there, which I would **not** suggest for many reasons. Otherwise you will have to submit the client data back to the server either by doing a full page refresh or using JS like @msg suggested.